# Differential equations - The Existence and Uniqueness Theorem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

So I am going to train my skills in this course. I have to work with this exercise:

"Let $ϕ_0 (t)=0$ and use the method of successive approximations to solve the given IVP.
\begin{equation}y'=2(y+1),y(0)=0\end{equation}

(a) Determine $ϕ_n(t)$ for an arbitrary value of $n$.

(b) Express $\lim_{n→∞}⁡ϕ_n(t)=ϕ(t)$ in terms of elementary functions, that is solve the given IVP.
"

So I already did part (a), and obtain
$ϕ_n(t)=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{(2t)^k}{k!}$

The part (b) is annoying me. I tried to compute $\lim_{n→∞}⁡ϕ_n(t)=ϕ(t)$ using Maple and obtain $ϕ(t)=e^{2t}-1$ my own idea is to use infinite geometric series but I am not sure how to find the function ϕ(t) using the finite geometric series.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Do you know the [power series for the exponential function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_function#Formal_definition)? You really should.

Comment: Ahh! That's true, how could I forget this...